# Difference between cucumber and citrus framework

Tags: continuous-integration, cucumber, integration-testing, citrus-framework

For my functional and technical tests, I use cucumber but my new team will use citrus framework for cucumber tests in addition to cucumber :o . What is the difference? Can I just use the same features in both ? And why do we use the both, what can we win ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: (a very simplified explanation) **a)** Cucumber - Behavior Driven Development, you define the behavior (the executed tests) of your application **before** you start the coding, **b)** Citrus framework - execute automated integration tests to check the behavior of your **already coded* application connected to external services. The scopes are completely different. Cucumber - to verify the behavior when you change your code, Citrus - to verify the behavior when you replace for example one JMS provider by another one.

Comment: Thank you. So if I understand , the scopes are different it's a non sense to launch same tests on both ?

Comment: Yes. I would see it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cucumber enables you to follow the BDD concepts by defining your test logic in form of feature specifications with Gherkin Given-When-Then syntax. Cucumber then makes those specs executable with unit testing code for Java and other programming languages.

Citrus lets you write integration tests in Java or XML with focus on messaging integration with client and server side communication over various message transports.

It is totally useful to combine Cucumber and Citrus in order to get BDD enabled integration tests where you use Cucumber for reading the Gherkin feature specifications and Citrus for executing the message based integration logic in your test.

In fact Cucumber and Citrus provide perfect integration with each other. Citrus provides predefined Cucumber BDD step implementations for sending and receiving messages over different messaging transports. You can also use predefined step implementations to use Selenium within Citrus and Cucumber so you end up just writing your Gherkin feature specification and all the glue code is provided out-of-the-box.

Here is an example for this setup: https://github.com/christophd/citrus-demo-devoxx-be